# ClickOnce or Windows installer for autoupdating a C# application?

Tags: c#, windows-installer, clickonce

Should I use a ClickOnce or Windows installer to get my application autoupdate?

My situation is that, I have a C# Windows application that is running [MySQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL) queries to a database which I maintain through a web hosting service (webmasters.com).

The program is now used by three different people and I just to copy pasted the release folder to their computers and installed the MySQL connector and [.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework) framework 4 client on their computers and just run the executable (.exe). This doesn't sound very professional and I was thinking, since I enjoy working with this project, why not to make something correct and professional instead of patches and fixes and learn from my experience?

So I was thinking to create a setup and deployment project which will be used to install the program to others computers. Also in this setup and deployment project the mysql connector and .NET framework is going to be included and will install these along with the software. One installer for all.

Moreover, I was thinking that the program needs an update service so that every time I change something in the code I don't have to run over to peoples' homes to change the program. So I created an [FTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Transfer_Protocol) site where I can upload files and when the program runs it will check for updates on the FTP site and if any new files were uploaded it will download them and continue with the new version. I read about ClickOnce applications, but I didnt quite understand how this works.

I have read *[Deploying C# Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173084%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)*  (MSDN), but what should I chose to accomplish this and make my program more professional and not just a student's homework?

Comment: I like the xcopy way to auto detect latest version files from network shard folder. It is more easy to implement.  For Example, you can include bat files into setup project as below: @echo off
echo COPYING UPDATE. DO NOT CLOSE THIS WINDOW.
xcopy "\\ShardFolder\\*.*" "C:\Your WinForm Application\" /s /d /y
echo COPYING UPDATE COMPLETE. START LAUNCH APPLICATION. DO NOT CLOSE THIS WINDOW.
cd "C:\Your WinForm Application Install Folder"
YourWinFormAPP inputParameters
exit   Then, create shortcut in setup project to call this bat file.

Answer (score 9):

One thing to be aware of is that ClickOnce always installs in the current users' context.  If they have a need to make this application available to anyone logged into that machine, this model will fail.

MSI installers using the setup facility in Visual Studio will definitely give you a more flexible installation experience.  Besides the fact that you define what goes into your application folder and what your startup folder looks like it allows custom installer components.  So if you need to have people install your application but enter a server path based on their location.

One element you skipped over is other install tools.  There are primarily two on the marketplace: Wise and Install Shield.  These are also good tools and I know you can at least construct your Install Shield inside Visual Studio.  The professional versions make it easier to incorporate path installers that avoid the uninstall/install problem mentioned by David Stratton.

Comment: +1 for pointing out another issue with ClickOnce AND for expanding on professional tools.

Answer (score 6):

Having done all three, I prefer to just deploy via drag and drop ([XCOPY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XCOPY_deployment)) deployment for Windows applications, which means manually installing prerequisites first.

- ClikOnce is nice - until you need to retire the server it's hosted on, or the certificate expires, or a few other minor issues I had to deal with.  Other than this, it's an extremely powerful, and simple way to keep your user's applications updated.

  - To be fair, all of the issues I ran across have answers and it's possible to avoid them, but the documentation doesn't tell you "to avoid this, do this". For me it was all "learn as you go". It'd be helpful to have a planning guide to explain the common pitfalls up front.
- [MSI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Installer) installers are nice as well, but it means uninstalling/reinstalling to update.
- Drag and drop - simplistic and not as flashy, but if I want to make a minor update, I can just copy in the new files.

All of that said, there are advantages and disadvantages to all approaches, but in 95% of my deployments, *which are in a corporate setting, deploying to our own users*, I prefer XCOPY deployment.

*If I were delivering software to outside customers*, I'd go with an installer built with a professional tool.

That said, Microsoft has provided a [good article on choosing between ClickOnce or an MSI Installer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973805.aspx).  It doesn't address XCOPY at all, but then again, XCOPY is so simple to understand it's probably not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

If you can open source your code then [CodePlex](http://www.codeplex.com/) provides ClickOnce hosting for your installer. *[ClickOnce Releases](http://codeplex.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=ClickOnce)* explains how to set it up. I'm using it for [my sample project](http://localdbcompanion.codeplex.com/), and it works great. After I publish an update, all clients get updated automatically at the first start.

Comment: what i did so far. I created an ftp site and when i publish my application, it is published in this location. When you want to run the application, browse the ftp site with an ftp client (ex filezilla) and drag and drop the application to your computer. Now i want to make it autoupdate. Like when i publish a newer version, when you run the software, it checks for newer version but it doesnt downloads it. It sticks with the old version. How can i succed this?

Comment: I would think very hard before trying to reinvent an existing solution. Unless your goal is to simply learn how it could work.

Comment: i am trying to learn how click once works. But i didn't manage to understand how auto update works