# Winform application changes as updates...?

Tags: windows, winforms

I've developed one winform(windows) application(.exe) for our client in c#. They have approx. 200 system on which this application installed. It is right now on testing stage, so if there is any minor label change or something like that, every time I have to build my project and provide them new executable(.exe).

Is it possible to give them only updated changes which all 100's of system will installed, rather installing whole new exe.

Comment: You're looking for ClickOnce.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can use [Click Once](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wh45kb66(v=vs.90).aspx). It is quite easy to use and deploy and you will not have to write a custom code. It also has some limitations but it is a good point of start. It can work in the following way:

1. You prepare Click Once package with your application.
2. What is important you should force auto update on start.
3. You publish the prepared package to a web site, a file path or a web site.
4. Users install the application from the given location.
5. Every time you changed something in the application you also have to publish a new Click Once package.
6. The new version will be automatically downloaded the next time the application is run.

Comment: Hello Michal I know about clickonce but also know about the drawback come with it, my application uses many resource files, interop service for converting docx to pdf etc. So I've create windows installer project. Now is it possible all with clickonce or in combination

Comment: As far as I know windows installer project has limited support for auto update. See these questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2618401/does-windows-installer-provide-a-method-to-update-applications, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11058382/clickonce-or-windows-installer-for-autoupdating-a-c-sharp-application

Comment: As to limitations of Click Once. I don't see a reason why for example many resource files can be a problem. Do you have any specific problem in mind?

Comment: Yes, Michal as I Used microsoft office interop service for creating docx and converting them to different format, even I used wia library for scanner and media drivers. I think this will create issue if I go for click once.

Answer (score -1):

It depends on the type of upgrade that you are required to make and the type of deployment you chose initially.

However, generally, you can't just have a "patch" (update) that will literally "redraw" a "Label" control of your initial winform (if I get you right on "if there is any minor label change ")

A trick I did sometimes was to have an "pseudo" executable (e.g. say MyAppLauncher.exe) that launches the actual executable (e.g. say MyMainProgram.exe), which intermittently checks online for a token that makes MyAppLauncher.exe decide if to download a new version of MyMainProgram.exe or just run the already installed local version.

In that way, you can be sure to have "smoother" upgrades of several components of your app, if you plan it so.