# Best method to deploy an auto update technique

Tags: .net, deployment, desktop-application, auto-update

I want to implement an auto update technique for my desktop app.

Are there any good API's to use? I need a very simple "exe" updater...

I am looking at

- oneclickdeployment
- possible 3rd party API's
- Rolling my own basic auto updater.

Should I just roll my own and get it over and done with?

Answer (score 0):

It is matter of opinion what is good or not. However, if you need a simple solution I think that [Click Once](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d.aspx) is a good option. I used it a few times in the past and it worked well. See also my recent [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25883668/winform-application-changes-as-updates/25884425#25884425).